# compiling cocos3d 0.7.2 with Xcode5 error

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5, cocos3d

I tried to compile my cocos3d 0.7.2 project with xcode5. I am already stuck at the first error I get with the line “super.parent = aNode;” in CC3ParametricMeshNodes.m.

this line is in the setParent function:

```
-(void) setParent: (CC3Node*) aNode {
super.parent = aNode;
[self deriveNameFrom: aNode];
if ( !mesh ) self.box = self.parentBoundingBox;
}
```

and the error I get is:

> CC3ParametricMeshNodes.m:246:15: Assignment to readonly property

I am sure that there will be other errors after this one is fixed. Is there any topic on common errors that occur while compiling cocos3d 0.7.2 with Xcode5?

Thanks

Comment: Is that the newest version?  I can't find that function on GitHub

Comment: Alright now that I look at it, that version seems to be over a year old.  So basically, there are no "common errors" because no one is trying to compile it anymore.  You should consider updating.

Comment: you can change `super.parent = aNode` to `[super setParent:aNode]`. I'm using pretty old version too and this worked for me

Comment: That now no longer works. It gives "Incompatible pointer types sending CC3Node to parameter of type MatchLocation"